# Mega API using python programming language

Tags: python, windows

I want to be able to access my Mega account using python. I looked to the following link but I have issues concerning the login process.

https://github.com/richardasaurus/mega.py

With the examples given, it looks quite easy

```
mega = Mega()
m = mega.login(email, password)
```

But when I do it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mega\mega.py", line 26, in login
    instance.login_user(email, password)
  File "mega\mega.py", line 32, in login_user
    resp = self.api_request({'a': 'us', 'user': email, 'uh': uh})
  File "mega\mega.py", line 86, in api_request
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "requests\api.py", line 84, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "requests\api.py", line 39, in request
    return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 200, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "requests\models.py", line 489, in send
    cert_loc = __import__('certifi').where()
ImportError: No module named certifi
```

I guess I did not install correctly mega.py but I can't make it work.
Thanks

Comment: The error log complains about a missing module named `certifi`. Make sure you have installed it in your system (possibly via a tool like `pip`).

Comment: I'm under windows --
The module certifi does not seem to exist, maybe in requests or something?

Comment: Looks like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi is missing, don't know if it works on deprecated OSes, but can't try, only have Debian here.

Comment: Thank you @JulienPalard !
Now the certifi problem is resolved.

But I have another bug, still when I do mega.login(email, password)
This give http://pastebin.com/KDQj3Ywg

Comment: What is in req.text ?

Comment: I don't know I searched it in \Python27\ and I didn't found anything.

Comment: @JulienPalard I think its a task called by the mega module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in comments, the solution is just to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi